# URL rewrite error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I trying to rewrite url

```
site.com/videos?cat=1&page=2
```

to this

```
site.com/videos/cat-1/page-2
```

and using this:

```
RewriteRule ^videos/cat-([0-9]+)/page-([0-9]+)/?$ videos?cat=$1&page=$2
RewriteRule ^videos/cat-([0-9]+)/?$ videos?cat=$1
```

I get error #500 (Internal Server Error). What can be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you're causing infinite looping in Apache mod_rewrite and that's causing 500.

Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# to redirect /videos?cat=1&page=2 => /videos/cat-1/page-2
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(videos)\?cat=([^&]+)&page=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/cat-%2/page-%3? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^.+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^videos/cat-([0-9]+)/?$ /videos?cat=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# to forward /videos/cat-1/page-2 => /videos?cat=1&page=2
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^.+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^videos/cat-([0-9]+)/page-([0-9]+)/?$ /videos?cat=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually work. I don't understand some of the parameters but I'll search them in the net.

Comment: Yes it should work, for any problem pls leave a comment. For guide to mod_rewrite use: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/

Comment: Actually now this return `"Object not found!"` any idea why?

Comment: What was your URI that you used to test?

Comment: I think I don't understand you? I use this in my .htaccess and just open the link in the site. Should rewrite it to `site.com/videos/cat-1/page-2` but i get `"Object not found!"` instead.

Comment: Just for your understanding I asked your URI and it seems answer is: `site.com/videos?cat=1&page=2`. Now as per above rule it should be redirected to: `site.com/videos/cat-1/page-2` and I have tested it too. Can you post your latest & complete .htaccess in your question and tell me where it is actually places in your directory structure.

Comment: Its only this in my .htaccess file. When I load in my browser `site.com/videos?cat=1&page=2` i get this error. .htaccess file is in my root directory.

Comment: EDIT: After I load URL is rewrited to `site.com/videos/cat-1/page-2%20HTTP/1.1` not to `site.com/videos/cat-1/page-2`

Answer (score 3):

That looks correct, but what you're trying to do is actually the other way round - you're trying to rewrite the input url:

```
site.com/videos/cat-1/page-2
```

To:

```
site.com/videos?cat=1&page=2
```

**EDIT**
You've written your rule to redirect from `videos/cat-1/page-2` to `videos?cat=1&page=2`. While this is your choice, if you're writing a rule for SEO purposes or for cleaner urls then the url you want people to enter is `videos/cat-1/page-2` - in which case, the rule you have will work fine.

If you want people to enter the messier url, then @anubhava's answer is perfect for you.

Comment: How to made it in proper way?

Comment: The rule is fine - are you entering `site.com/videos/cat-1/page-2` in the browser or `site.com/videos?cat=1&page=2`?

Comment: `site.com/videos?cat=1&page=2` like this

Comment: Sounds like you have totally misunderstood the question. He intended the opposite but wrote the rule wrong.

Comment: Which is what I have clarified in my edit. I think it's worth pointing out that the OP is writing the rule against the usual policy (of clean urls) and I was trying to point out why the rule looked like it would fit the situation but did not

Comment: Yes I need when people enter messier url to rewrite this url to `videos/cat-1/page-2`